# Need absolute path for scripts

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How can i replace `src="/js/main.js?v=7112018"` path on absolute path?

For example, i have `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js?v=7112018"></script>`

and i want, that my src will

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.recr.local/js/main.js?v=7112018"></script>`

I'm using `"webpack": "^4.4.1"`, `"react": "16.3.0"`

See the screenshot below

[image]

I need to make absolute path's for proxy site.

Answer (score 0):

Change your publicPath property under output:

```
output: {
  publicPath: 'app.recr.local/'
}
```

Comment: done. Some images crashed, and path's still the same :(

Comment: paste your webpack config

Comment: And why exactly do you need the full path?

Comment: for proxy site, i try to add webpack config but SO think that is too much code in my question :) wait for a minute pls

Comment: It is right... what was the output on the html? How did the url become?

Comment: it's become the same src="/js/main.js?v=7112018"

Comment: well, something else is not right, or this is coming from elsewhere, the config is right. I have no idea.

Comment: how those paths are inserted into html?

Comment: react or webpack, sorry i don`t now 100%

Comment: I don't see html-webpack-plugin. So i have no idea how it is done either. It was supposed to be html-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The **webpack.config.js** file has two options, which are, the output.path, where it stores all the output files locally, and output.publicPath which indicates where all the JS and CSS files as well as all your assets will be on the server. So you can change the value of output.publicPath to the corresponding server your are using.